# How do I format my Windows 8.1 partition and keep my ubuntu partition as it is?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, format

My Laptop has Windows 8.1 and ubuntu (Although i use it less frequently than windows). I wanted to format my windows version as it has become really slower and battery draining is very bad. I wanted to know if I could do this without any affect on the ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can even do it from Ubuntu, first

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now run this

```
sudo gparted
```

Now find your Windows partition and right click and choose delete

[image]

Now click apply and Windows is gone, Ubuntu is untouched, and you can do whatever you want with the empty partition.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if I could do this without any affect on the Ubuntu partition.

Yes, this is possible.

As long as you do not touch the Ubuntu partitions during your formatting of Windows 8 you will be fine. And you can format the partition from either Windows or from Ubuntu (using gparted).

Windows will overwrite GRUB though and you will need to re-install it from the Ubuntu live session. There is a wiki page [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) on this.

Things to consider:

1. create a backup of the files you deem important.
2. Operating systems need to be installed with the same configuration. So no fast boot from Windows (it probably will default to this), make sure you either install with or without UEFI depending on how it is set up now (Windows probably will default to UEFI).